# Installing Azure SDK on an Azure box (kudu)

Tags: azure, continuous-deployment, kudu

I'm setting up deployment from source on Windows Azure using kudu.

The project fails to build with the following message:

```
D:\home\site\repository\CliniscanAzure\CliniscanAzure.ccproj(62,3): error MSB4019: 
The imported project "D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\
Windows Azure Tools\2.4\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" was not found. Confirm that 
the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Using the diagnostic console on the target box, I can see that "D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\" exists, but not the Windows Azure Tools subdirectory.

Is the correct solution to install the Azure 2.4 SDK on my target box? If so, what's the correct way to do that? I don't see any way to add that particular installation to my deployment script.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this target file relates to deploying Cloud Services, which are quite different from Websites. With Websites, you should not need this dependency at all.

Comment: You know, it's amazing how far you can get with trying to deploy a cloud service as a website on Azure with kudu...

Comment: I guess I've never tried that. :) But one key design goal of Websites is that it doesn't need any of those special Cloud Service libraries, and you can just use a 'regular' app.